# cannot determine user id for 'vagrant', does the user exist on this system?

Tags: vagrant, digital-ocean

I try to provision vagrant box on digital ocean, but chef solo fails with

```
==> ds_cabinet_do: Chef::Exceptions::UserIDNotFound
==> ds_cabinet_do: --------------------------------
==> ds_cabinet_do: cannot determine user id for 'vagrant', does the user exist on this system?
```

Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
  1 Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  2   config.vm.define :ds_cabinet_do do |config|
  3     config.vm.hostname = 'cabinet'
  4     config.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 3000, host: 3000
  5 
  6     #according to https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-digitalocean
  7     config.vm.provider :digital_ocean do |provider, override|
  8       override.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/id_do_vbox'
  9       override.vm.box = 'digital_ocean'
 10       override.vm.box_url = 'https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-digitalocean/raw/master/box/digital_ocean.box'
 11 
 12       provider.token = 'b6c724f53dca64df5e5310e042852e89ea6b6ca1492c45f17a584041aaf71200'
 13       provider.image = '14.10 x64'
 14       provider.region = 'nyc2' #['nyc1', 'ams1', 'sfo1', 'nyc2', 'ams2', 'sgp1', 'lon1', 'nyc3', 'ams3']]
 15       provider.size = '512mb'
 16     end
 17 
 18     #config.vm.synced_folder '../..', '/home/vagrant/my_src'
 19     config.ssh.forward_agent = true # to use host keys added to agent
 20 
 21     # provisioning
 22     config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'sudo apt-get update'
 23     config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'sudo apt-get install ruby2.1-dev build-essential'
 24     config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'sudo gem install chef --version=11.8.2 --no-ri --no-rdoc'
 25 
 26     config.vm.provision 'chef_solo' do |chef|
 27       chef.log_level = 'info'
 28       chef.environment = 'development'
 29       chef.environments_path = 'environments'
 30       chef.cookbooks_path = ['cookbooks', 'site-cookbooks']
 31       chef.roles_path = 'roles'
 32       chef.data_bags_path = 'data_bags'
 33       chef.json.merge!(JSON.parse(IO.read('nodes/10.2.2.15.json')))
 34     end
 35   end
 36 end
```

It looks like there is no user `vagrant` in the system 'cause there is no corresponding line in `/etc/passwd` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you already have your answer, but allow me to try and clear thing up further.

The `vagrant` user is historically the default user Vagrant uses to SSH into its boxes. It was created as a standard means of access to the VMs. VirtualBox (and probably all other local hypervisors supported by Vagrant) base boxes have this user baked in with the `insecure_private_key` pre-authorised. This key is the same across all Vagrant installations, which has 2 basic corollaries:

- as the name implies, it's insecure (one of the reasons why Vagrant is seen as a dev only technology)
- it allows us to share base boxes without having to worry about authentication

Please keep in mind that when Vagrant was created it was coupled to VirtualBox. Other hypervisors and cloud providers were added much later.

The cloud works in a very different way from local hypervisors. Authentication is usually not baked in the VM images, so using the insecure key is not an option. You would probably not want that anyway, as it would leave your cloud Vagrant instances open to the world as anyone can get hold of the key.

If you read the [README for the DigitalOcean provider](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-digitalocean) you'll see that one of the features is

"setup a SSH public key for authentication"

That key will be setup on whatever user is the default admin for the VM image you're using (might be `root`, might be `ubuntu`, etc).

You shouldn't assume that the user `vagrant` exists there. Chances are it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, cassianoleal!